# Django - I am unable to post data in db through a form. Why?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Book

class BookCreateForm(forms.Form):
   title = forms.CharField(required=True)
   author = forms.CharField(required=True)
   description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
   genre = forms.CharField(required=True)
   book_image = forms.ImageField(required=True)
   publishedDate = 
   forms.DateField(widget=forms.widgets.DateInput(format="%m/%d/%Y"))
   price =forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=8)
   stock = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Book(models.Model):
    title         = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    author        = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description   = models.TextField()
    genre         = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    book_image    = models.ImageField()
    publishedDate = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    price         = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    stock         = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)


class Quote(models.Model):
    quote_name = models.TextField()
    quote_author = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import  HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView,ListView,DetailView
from .models import Book
from .forms import BookCreateForm

# Create your views here.

def book_createview(request):
    template_name='bookstores/addbook.html'
    # print (request.GET)
    # print (request.POST)
    if request.method == "GET":
         print ("Get ")
         print(request.GET)
    if request.method == "POST":
         print("post data")
         print (request.POST)
    formed=BookCreateForm()
    form = BookCreateForm(request.POST)

if form.is_valid():
    obj =Book.objects.create(
        title=form.cleaned_data.get('title'),
        author=form.cleaned_data.get('author'),
        description=form.cleaned_data.get('description'),
        genre=form.cleaned_data.get('genre'),
        book_image = form.cleaned_data.get('book_image'),
        publishedDate = form.cleaned_data.get('publishedData'),
        price = form.cleaned_data.get('price'),
        stock = form.cleaned_data.get('stock')
    )
if form.errors:
    print (form.errors)

    #return  HttpResponseRedirect("/store/")

context ={}
return render(request,template_name,context)
```

TemplateView:

```
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% block head_title %}Adding book || {{ block.super }} {% endblock 
 head_title %}
{% block content %}
<p><i>tell us about the book you liked</i></p>
<div class ="form-group">
<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" name ='title' placeholder="Title"><br>
<input type="text" name ='author' placeholder="author"><br>
<input type="text" name ='description' placeholder="description"><br>
<input type="text" name ='genre' placeholder="genre"><br>
<input type="text" name ='book_image' placeholder="book_image"><br>
<input type="text" name ='price' placeholder="price"><br>
<input type="text" name ='stockk' placeholder="stock"><br>


<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock  %}
```

The error that I am getting is :

> Get
>
> title
>
> This field is
>   required.
>
> author
>
> This field
>   is required.
>
> description
>
> This field is
>   required.
>
> genre
>
> This field
>   is required.
>
> book_image
>
> This field is
>   required.
>
> publishedDate
>
> This field is
>   required.
>
> price
>
> This field
>   is required.
>
> stock
>
> This
>   field is required.
>
> [15/Nov/2017 12:38:27] "GET
>   /addbook/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2375 post data https://images.gr-assets.com/books/1506565784l/30835567.jpg'],
>   'price': ['1045.36'], 'stockk': ['40']}>
>
> book_image
>
> This field
>   is required.
>
> publishedDate
>
> This field is
>   required.
>
> stock

Comment: why not using Django CreateView its more easier read [this](http://setthecode.pythonanywhere.com/post?id=22)

Comment: can you print out request.POST, i guess it will be empty since you are sending a GET request instead of POST

Comment: change `<form method="POST"> `   to `<form method="post" action="."> ` also you code seems to mis aligned please currect that so that every one can asses the problem easily

Comment: 1) formed=BookCreateForm() in get  formed=BookCreateForm(request.post) in post method, 2) Use proper Django Class based View  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. when you are making `GET` request you are creating Book object. you should not do that.
2. when you are making `POST` request.

   a. **book_image** key is not coming which you can seen in post data.

   b. from form **stockk** is coming for **stock**. There is typing mistake.

   c. **publishedDate** will not come via form.

Comment: when you are making GET request you are creating Book object. you should not do that. ? what do you mean by you should not create like that?

Comment: GET is for fetching not for creating. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET